# jqgrid read in embedded json objects

Tags: json, date, object, jqgrid

Hey guys so I am currently using jqgrid with json data and it currently reads in fine but i am having some difficulties getting an embeded object to read into the grid. So my json data looks something like this:

```
{"total":1,"page":"1","records":1,"rows":[{"Cell1":1,"Cell2":"stuff","Cell3":{"date":"2013-06-02 10:56:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}}]}
```

Does anyone know how i can get jqgrid to read in Cell3 as one piece of data and interpret it to just display the date and time?

my current json reader is as follows:

```
    jsonReader : {
  root:"rows",
  page: "page",
  total: "total",
  records: "records",
  repeatitems: false,
  id: "0"
}
```

Thanks again everyone

Comment: It would be better if you includes more full JavaScript code which you use. For example the value of `datatype` is very important. If you use `datatype: "json"` then it's important whether you use `loadonce: true`. Do you load the data in TreeGrid or in other not a simple grid?

Comment: @Oleg currently my grid looks like:
        datatype: "json",
  jsonReader : {
   root:"rows",
   page: "page",
   total: "total",
   records: "records",
   repeatitems: false,
   id: "0"
  }, sortable:true,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
 autowidth:true,
 multipleSearch:true,
I do not have load once set and the datatype is json. Please let me know if there is any other information you need and thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the options `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "0"}` are incorrect. Integer values of `id` can be used in case of usage default `repeatitems: true` setting. In the case the data which represent the row of the grid looks like array `["1", "Cell2"]` and not as object with named properties `{"Cell1": 1, "Cell2": "stuff"}`. You should use `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "Cell1"}` if `Cell1` contains the value which you want to use as unique `id` of the row of the grid.

Now back to your main question. I recommend you to change format of the data from

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": "1",
    "records": 1,
    "rows": [
        {
            "Cell1": 1,
            "Cell2": "stuff",
            "Cell3": {
                "date": "2013-06-02 10:56:00",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

to

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": "1",
    "records": 1,
    "rows": [
        {
            "Cell1": 1,
            "Cell2": "stuff"
        }
    ],
    "userdata": {
        "1": {
            "date": "2013-06-02 10:56:00",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        }
    }
}
```

I want comment my suggestion so that it could be clear for other users too. The column `Cell1` contains the `id`. The structure of `userdata` which I suggest is the map from rowid (the value of `Cell1`) and the custom information which you need save as `"Cell3"` originally.

If you need somewhere in your code to have the `"Cell3"` value the code will be like below

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    var cell3 = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData")[rowid];
    // now you can use cell3 which coniains the object like
    // {
    //     "date": "2013-06-02 10:56:00",
    //     "timezone_type": 3,
    //     "timezone": "UTC"
    // }
}
```